# Hide/Show React-slick arrows

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I am using react-slick and I have my own customised arrows. This Slider is NOT an infinite loop and I would like to hide the arrows at the start and end of the loop. So basically at start PrevArrow should be hidden and at the end the NextArrow should be hidden. Which I am trying to set hidden class name depending on state changes. However the class name is not changing although the state is changing correctly. Do you know what's the problem with this code? and how to get it work?

Below is my setting for Slider and the component which renders Slider.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import Arrow from '../slider/Arrow';


export default class CityCarousel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displayLeftArrow: true,
            displayRightArrow: true
        };


        this.slidesToShow = 5;
        this.sliderSetting = {
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            infinite: false,
            initialSlide: 0,
            slidesToShow: this.slidesToShow,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            speed: 500,
            rows: 0,
            nextArrow: <Arrow
                    styleClassName={`city-carousel__right ${
                        this.state.displayRightArrow ? '' : 'city-carousel__right--hide'
                    }`}
                    direction="right"
                    clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
                />,
            prevArrow: <Arrow
                    styleClassName={`city-carousel__left ${
                        this.state.displayLeftArrow ? '' : 'city-carousel__left--hide'
                    }`}
                    direction="left"
                    clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
                />,
            afterChange: currentSlide => this.setArrowDisplay(currentSlide)
        };
    }

    clickHandler = direction => {
        if (direction === 'left') {
            this.slider.slickPrev();
        } else if (direction === 'right') {
            this.slider.slickNext();
        }
    };

    setArrowDisplay = currentSlide => {
        const { cityList } = this.props;
        const displayLeftArrow = currentSlide !== 0;
        const displayRightArrow = currentSlide !== cityList.length - this.slidesToShow;

        this.setState({ displayRightArrow, displayLeftArrow });
    };

    render() {
        const { cityList, tours } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="city-selection">
                    <Slider
                        ref={c => this.slider = c }
                        {...this.sliderSetting}
                    >
                        {cityList.length > 0 ? this.renderCityList() : null}
                    </Slider>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is also code for Arrow component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Arrow = ({ styleClassName, direction, clickHandler }) => {

    return(
    <div
        className={`slick-arrow--${direction} slider-arrow--${direction} ${styleClassName}`}
        onClick={e => clickHandler(direction)}
    />
)};

Arrow.propTypes = {
    styleClassName: PropTypes.string,
    direction: PropTypes.string,
    clickHandler: PropTypes.func
};

export default Arrow;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `react-slick` is not re-rendering `<Arrow />` with new props, and it's always with first initialized props setting.

I think the solution is to get `<Arrow />` out of slider like this:

```
    <div className="city-selection">
      <Arrow
        styleClassName={`city-carousel__right ${
          this.state.displayRightArrow ? '' : 'city-carousel__right--hide'
          }`}
        direction="right"
        clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
      />
      <Arrow
        styleClassName={`city-carousel__left ${
          this.state.displayLeftArrow ? '' : 'city-carousel__left--hide'
          }`}
        direction="left"
        clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
      />
      <Slider
        {/* list of items*/}
      </Slider>
    </div>
```

you can see how it's working in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-bug-fix?file=index.js)

Comment: I think a better way is to edit the css files to override the default behaviour.

In your app.css, you can use `.slick-disabled { opacity: 0% !important;  }` to make the button transparent while disabled

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, we have boolean arrows, just declare it false in settings.

```
 const settings = {
        ...,
        arrows: false,
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the current slide prop to the component and do a check for the slide you want to trigger hiding the arrow:

```
function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
    const { currentSlide, className, onClick } = props;
    if (currentSlide === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return <div className={className} onClick={onClick} />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `this.sliderSettings` set `nextArrow` & `prevArrow` for your Arrow component do something like this

```
<Arrow 
  styleClassName={'YOUR_CLASSES_HERE'}
  direction="right" 
  clickHandler={this.clickHandler} 
  isHidden={this.state.isHidden} 
/>
```

Where `this.state.isHidden` is the state variable where you are trying toggle the arrows.

Then in your `Arrow` component do something like this.

```
 const Arrow = ({ styleClassName, direction, clickHandler, isHidden }) => {

   return (
    <div
     className={`slick-arrow--${direction} slider-arrow--${direction} 
                ${styleClassName}`}
     style={{ display: isHidden: 'none': 'block' }}
     onClick={e => clickHandler(direction)}
    />
   )
 };
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested still not working - I confirm that states are changing however when I console log it in arrow it's still old values not the updated state

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly have a look at the `Arrow` component.

Comment: Still not working ... Do you have a jsFiddler example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best manual controls over the arrow then use a **custom arrow**.

1. Create it by using a simple Arrow component.
2. Set the `onClick` handler of that component by using a `ref` in the main `Slider` component.

   ```
   const sliderRef = useRef<Slider>(null);

   <Slider {...settings} ref={sliderRef}>
   ```
3. Use states to conditionally show or hide arrows.

I wrote a blog post which covers the workflow to achieve similar kind of functionalities you want. You can have a look there.

https://medium.com/@imasharaful/image-slider-with-react-slick-d54a049f043